# $\cos9x-\cos6x=2$, find the general solution for $x$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\cos9x-\cos6x=2$, find the general solution for $x$.

What I did was substituted $z=3x$ and I got $$4\cos^3z - 4\cos^2z-3\cos z=0$$
After which I got $\cos3x=0$, $\cos3x=-0.5$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Can you show how you got $4\cos^3z - 4\cos^2z-3\cos z=0$? I don't think it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

While you could reduce this to a cubic equation, there's a neater way: the equation is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases} \cos9x=1 \\[4px] \cos6x=-1 \end{cases}
$$
Can you see why?

---

What about your attempt? Setting $z=\cos3x$, is a good choice; then
$$
\cos9x=4\cos^33x-3\cos3x=4z^3-3z
$$
so the equation becomes, with $\cos6x=2\cos^23x-1=2z^2-1$,
$$
4z^3-3z-2z^2+1=2
$$
that simplifies to
$$
4z^3-2z^2-3z-1=0
$$
which is quite different from yours. The polynomial function has a local maximum before $0$ where it evaluates to a negative number; there is a local minimum between $0$ and $1$ and the value at $1$ is $-2$. Thus the polynomial has no roots between $-1$ and $1$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any solutions. Since $|cos(\theta)| \leq 1$, then $cos(9x)=1$ and $cos(6x)=-1$.

this means $6x=\pi +2m\pi$ and $9x=2n\pi$ with integers $m$ and $n$.

There are no pair of integers which satisfy that.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract both cosines as follows:

$$
\cos9x-\cos 6x=-2\cdot\sin\frac{9x+6x}{2}\cdot\sin\frac{9x-6x}{2}=-2\cdot\sin\frac{15x}{2}\cdot\sin\frac{3x}{2}.
$$

It is enough to solve

$$
\sin\frac{15x}{2}\cdot\sin\frac{3x}{2}=-1.
$$

There are 2 cases to analyse:
\begin{align*}
\sin\frac{15x}{2}=1\ \wedge\ \sin\frac{3x}{2}=-1\ \Rightarrow\ x=\frac{\pi}{15}+\frac 4{15}\,k\pi\ \wedge\ x=\pi+\frac 43\,l\pi,\ k,l\in\mathbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ \text{no solution}\\[16pt]
\sin\frac{15x}{2}=-1\ \wedge\ \sin\frac{3x}{2}=1\ \Rightarrow\ x=\frac{\pi}{5}+\frac 4{15}\,k\pi\ \wedge\ x=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac 43\,l\pi,\ k,l\in\mathbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ \text{no solution}
\end{align*}